# How to use switch case in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to use switch case in PHP to print out a date `f.ex 16. November 2019 + time`
I need to change the months to another language but it doesn't seem to work like this. Not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `strftime()` and set locale to Finnish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're echo'ing `$kuukausi` later, so `echo`'ing the Finnish translation in your switch would result in the wrong output:

```
Marraskuu16. November 2019 Kello 13:50:00
```

Instead, you need to overwrite `$kuukausi` in your switch:

```
case "November":
  $kuukausi = "Marraskuu";
  break;
```

Personally, I wouldn't use a switch for this.

As @Qirel mentioned in a comment, you can simply set the locale to Finnish and get the correct month straight away:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fi_FI', 'fin_fin', 'fi', 'fin');
$kuukausi = strftime('%B');
```

If the Finnish locale is not available on your server, I still wouldn't use a switch because it's just too much code for a relatively simple task. I'd prefer an array mapping based on a numerical index (`date('n')`):

```
$months = [
    1 => 'Tammikuu',
    2 => 'Helmikuu',
    3 => 'Maaliskuu',
    4 => 'Huhtikuu',
    5 => 'Toukokuu',
    6 => 'Kesäkuu',
    7 => 'Heinäkuu',
    8 => 'Elokuu',
    9 => 'Syyskuu',
    10 => 'Lokakuu',
    11 => 'Marraskuu',
    12 => 'Joulokuu'
];

$kuukausi = $months[date('n')];
```

Comment: Thank you - This helped and solved the problem. I really wouldn't use the switch case either but it was an assignment so it was kind of a must for it. But thank you!